# How to make nested ReactDOM.render with React 18

Tags: react-dom

here is simplyfied what i have in React17, there are reasons why i do this so:

```
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
render(
    <StrictMode>
        <App />
    </StrictMode>,
    rootElement
);

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createElement } from "react";

const html = `<div id="my-id">Hi<div/>`;

export default function App() {
  const fillMe = () => {
    const myDiv = document.getElementById("my-id");
    console.log("div", myDiv);
    const myComp = createElement("h1", { className: "greeting" }, "Hello");
    ReactDOM.render(myComp, myDiv);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={fillMe}>fill me</button>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So i have a ReactDOM.render for App and another ReactDOM.render inside App.
Migrate to React 18 i must use createRoot.
This works fine until i replace the seconds ReactDOM.render with createRoot.
Any ideas how to solve with React 18?

Replacing second ReactDOM.render with createRoot gives an error.